# Authentication failure for Iam Authentication on Postgres Cloud SQL through jdbc Hikari

Tags: java, postgresql, google-cloud-sql, hikaricp, cloud-sql-proxy

I am trying to connect to a Postgres Cloud SQL instance using JDBC SocketFactory per the documentation here : https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-sql-jdbc-socket-factory/blob/main/docs/jdbc-postgres.md

```
HikariDataSource pool = null;
HikariConfig config = new HikariConfig();

//String jdbcURL = String.format("jdbc:postgresql:///%s", DBNAME);
String jdbcURL = String.format("jdbc:postgresql:///%s?cloudSqlInstance=%s&socketFactory=com.google.cloud.sql.postgres.SocketFactory&user=%s&password=%s&enableIamAuth=true&sslmode=disable",DBNAME,CLOUDSQLINSTANCE,USER,PASSWORD);
Properties connProps = new Properties();
connProps.setProperty("user", USER);
connProps.setProperty("password", PASSWORD);
connProps.setProperty("sslmode", SSLMODE);
connProps.setProperty("socketFactory", SOCKETFACTORY);
connProps.setProperty("cloudSqlInstance", CLOUDSQLINSTANCE);
connProps.setProperty("enableIamAuth", ENABLEIAMAUTH);
connProps.setProperty("ipTypes","PRIVATE");
System.out.println("jdbcurl: " + jdbcURL);
config.setJdbcUrl(jdbcURL);
config.setDataSourceProperties(connProps);
config.setConnectionTimeout(10000); // 10s
try {
     pool = new HikariDataSource(config);
}
catch (Exception e){
    System.out.println(e.getMessage() + e.getMessage() );
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

The error I get is:

> com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool$PoolInitializationException: Failed
> to initialize pool: FATAL: password authentication failed for user
> "XXXXXX-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com"    at
> com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.throwPoolInitializationException(HikariPool.java:596)
> at
> com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:582)
> at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.(HikariPool.java:100)    at
> com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.(HikariDataSource.java:81)
> at
> com.aexp.ngbd.mdm.util.ConnectionUtil.createConnectionPool(ConnectionUtil.java:49)
> at
> com.aexp.ngbd.mdm.avro.AvroToSQLInsert.createSQLFile(AvroToSQLInsert.java:84)
> at
> com.aexp.ngbd.mdm.avro.ReadFromPubSub.lambda$subscribeWithAvroSchemaExample$0(ReadFromPubSub.java:48)
> at
> com.google.cloud.pubsub.v1.MessageDispatcher$4.run(MessageDispatcher.java:396)
> at
> java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
> at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
> at
> java.base/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:304)
> at
> java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
> at
> java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
> at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829) Caused by:
> org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FATAL: password authentication
> failed for user "XXXXXXXX-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com"
> at
> org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.doAuthentication(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:623)
> at
> org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.tryConnect(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:163)
> at
> org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:215)
> at
> org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:51)
> at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.(PgConnection.java:225)   at
> org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:466)     at
> org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:265)    at
> com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:121)
> at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:359)
> at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:201)
> at
> com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:470)
> at
> com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:561)
> ... 12 more

I am running the jar on a compute engine. I am able to use psql to connect to the PostgreSQL instance using the same ServiceAccount which has been enabled for IAM authentication. I am connecting through the cloud SQL auth proxy below:

> ```
> satish@XXXX-load:~$ psql "host=127.0.0.1 sslmode=disable dbname=mdm user=XXXXXXX-compute@developer port=1234"
> psql (11.14 (Debian 11.14-0+deb10u1), server 13.4)
> WARNING: psql major version 11, server major version 13.
>          Some psql features might not work.
> Type "help" for help.
>
> mdm=> \dt
> ```

My question is, how can I connect to the Postgres instance using only the ServiceAccount in Java?

Below is my pom.xml dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.cloud.sql</groupId>
    <artifactId>postgres-socket-factory</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
    <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
    <version>42.3.1</version>
</dependency>
```

`com.google.cloud.sql:postgres-socket-factory:1.4.2-dev` does not seem to be available in the maven central. Is this the problem? The latest version I was able to find is `1.4.2`

Even if I use the `XXXXXXX-compute@developer` user, i still get the below error.

> Failed to initialize pool: FATAL: Cloud SQL IAM service account
> authentication failed for user "470754621570-compute@developer"Failed
> to initialize pool: FATAL: Cloud SQL IAM service account
> authentication failed for user "470754621570-compute@developer"
> com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool$PoolInitializationException: Failed
> to initialize pool: FATAL: Cloud SQL IAM service account
> authentication failed for user "470754621570-compute@developer"   at
> com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.throwPoolInitializationException(HikariPool.java:596)
> at
> com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:582)
> at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.(HikariPool.java:100)    at
> com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.(HikariDataSource.java:81)
> at
> com.aexp.ngbd.mdm.util.ConnectionUtil.createConnectionPool(ConnectionUtil.java:52)
> at
> com.aexp.ngbd.mdm.avro.AvroToSQLInsert.convertAvroToPostgres(AvroToSQLInsert.java:37)
> at
> com.aexp.ngbd.mdm.avro.AvroToSQLInsert.createSQLFile(AvroToSQLInsert.java:163)
> at
> com.aexp.ngbd.mdm.avro.ReadFromPubSub.lambda$subscribeWithAvroSchemaExample$0(ReadFromPubSub.java:51)
> at
> com.google.cloud.pubsub.v1.MessageDispatcher$4.run(MessageDispatcher.java:396)
> at
> java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
> at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
> at
> java.base/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:304)
> at
> java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
> at
> java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
> at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) Caused by:
> org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FATAL: Cloud SQL IAM service
> account authentication failed for user
> "470754621570-compute@developer"  at
> org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.doAuthentication(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:623)
> at
> org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.tryConnect(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:163)
> at
> org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:215)
> at
> org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:51)
> at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.(PgConnection.java:225)   at
> org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:466)     at
> org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:265)    at
> com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:121)
> at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:359)
> at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:201)
> at
> com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:470)
> at
> com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:561)
> ... 13 more

Comment: Please, consider review [this GCP documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/add-manage-iam-users), especially the section labeled [Troubleshoot a login failure](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/add-manage-iam-users#troubleshooting-a-login-failure), and check the [Postgres logs](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/logging), they may show details about the error that could be of help. I hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Answering this here in addition to the issue.

The dev artifact is a typo in the README. 1.4.2 is the latest public artifact.

Also, your user name should be `XXXXXX-compute@developer` (leaving off the `gserviceaccount.com`).

Comment: Still doesn't work. Updated original post.
Am I missing something here? Just supplying the service account name shouldn't be sufficient to access the DB!!? What am I missing here? An how does the cloud auth proxy binary service come into play here? I followed all the GitHub/Google docs, but no luck in figuring this out.

Comment: Actually, i was trying to make it work from my local machine. it worked when I used on the compute engine since I was using the compute engine ervice account.